# difference between sh and bash when symlink is used

Tags: bash, sh, symlink

I have a shell script which uses `process substitution`

The script is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  while read line
  do
    echo "$line"
  done < <( grep "^abcd$" file.txt )
```

When I run the script using `sh file.sh` I get the following output

```
$sh file.sh
file.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
file.sh: line 5: `done < <( grep "^abcd$" file.txt )'
```

When I run the script using `bash file.sh`, the script works.

Interestingly, `sh` is a `soft-link` mapped to `/bin/bash`.

```
$ which bash
/bin/bash
$ which sh
/usr/bin/sh
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 23  2012 /usr/bin/sh -> /bin/bash
$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 648016 Jul 12  2012 /bin/bash
```

I tested to make sure symbolic links are being followed in my shell using the following:

```
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ ln -s a.out a.link
$ ./a.link
hello world
$ ls -l a.out
-rwx--x--x 1 xxxx xxxx 16614 Dec 27 19:53 a.out
$ ls -l a.link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxx xxxx 5 May 14 14:12 a.link -> a.out
```

I am unable to understand why `sh file.sh` does not execute as `/bin/bash file.sh` since `sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.

Any insights will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you aren't executing bash because `/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH` and there is a `sh` program in `/bin`.

Comment: but `which sh` shows `/bin/sh` which points to `/bin/bash`...thus should not be `/bin/bash` be executed? Thanks

Comment: Hmm. But it's obvious sh and bash dont execute the same program.

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to understand..why?

Comment: Hmm. Very strange problem. I'm getting the same results as you on my machine. If i just type sh i get into the sh interprenter, not bash. Maybe its hardcoded in the system or something.

Comment: It's not a problem. `bash` is executed, but it detects that it is started using the name `sh` and behaves accordingly: as a (nearly) strictly compliant POSIX shell. One consequence of that is that it does not recognize process substitutions.

Comment: @Lennart Please see William's answer below. When `bash` is executed as `sh`, it enters in `POSIX` mode...and does not run in normal `bash` mode. So if I execute as `bash --posix file.sh`, I get the same error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @chepner Thanks..I understand the difference now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When invoked as sh, bash enters  posix
       mode after the startup files are read.  Process substitution is not recognized in posix mode.  According to posix, `<(foo)` should direct input from the file named `(foo)`.  (Well, that is, according to my reading of the standard.  The grammar is ambiguous in many places.)

EDIT: From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html):

```
The following list is what’s changed when ‘POSIX mode’ is in effect:
...
Process substitution is not available.
```

Comment: Since `sh` is a symblink to `bash` (see the output of `which` and `ls -l` in my question), should not executing `sh` command invoke `bash`? I am not concerned about why `sh file.sh` gives error, but why `sh file.sh` is not equivalent to `bash file.sh` when `sh` is symblink to `bash`. Thanks.

Comment: @Bill `sh file.sh` gives an error *because* `sh file.sh` is not equivalent to `bash file.sh`. `bash` simply parses and executes the same script differently when it is invoked as `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell since `sh` is symlink to `bash`, should not `bash` be executed? thats the meaning of symlinks, if I am not wrong...Please see the output of `which` and `ls -l` in the question. Thanks

Comment: @Bill `bash` *is* executed. From the `bash` man page: " If  bash  is  invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while
       conforming to the POSIX standard as well."