# Comparison of 2 string variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Consider there is a variable line and variable word:

```
line = 1234 abc xyz 5678
word = 1234
```

The value of these variables are read from 2 different files.

I want to print the line if it contains the word. How do I do this using shell script? I tried all the suggested solutions given in previous questions. For example, the following code always passed even if the word was not in the line.

```
if [ "$line"==*"$word"*]; then
    echo $line
fi
```

Comment: You might want to check out this old question that is one of the highest voted on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)

Comment: @Kevin: I already tried those answers and did not get the expected result. I have explained this in the question too.

Answer (score 4):

No need for an `if` statement;  just use `grep`:

```
echo $line | grep "\b$word\b"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `if [[ "$line" == *"$word"* ]]`

Also you need to use the following to assign variables

```
line="1234 abc xyz 5678"
word="1234"
```

Working example -- http://ideone.com/drLidd

Answer (score 4):

### Watch the white spaces!

When you set a variable to a value, don't put white spaces around the equal sign. Also use quotes when your value has spaced in it:

```
line="1234 abc xyz 5678"   # Must have quotation marks
word=1234                  # Quotation marks are optional
```

When you use comparisons, you **must** leave white space around the brackets and the comparison sign:

```
if [[ $line == *$word* ]]; then
    echo $line
fi
```

Note that double square brackets. If you are doing pattern matching, you ***must*** use the double square brackets and not the single square brackets. The double square brackets mean you're doing a pattern match operation when you use `==` or `=`. If you use single square brackets:

```
if [ "$line" = *"$word"* ]
```

You're doing equality. Note that double square brackets don't need quotation marks while single brackets it is required in most situations.

Comment: question: why "single brackets it is required in most situations."?

Comment: Ok, got it: [ $a == z* ]     # File globbing and word splitting take place.

Comment: The double brackets are a special _internal_ test and are not interpolated by the shell first. The single brackets, although they are now a builtin command, stem from the old `/bin/test` and `/bin/[` commands. The statement is fully interpolated by the shell first, and then the test is done. Thus, if `line="This is a test"`, you couldn't do `[ $line = "foo" ]` because the shell will replace `$line` and then think there are too many parameters for the test command. However, `[[ $line = "foo" ]]` is fine.

Comment: @DavidW.: Thanks for the detailed explanation on the use of brackets. It worked when I used bash. But why does this does not work with sh?

Comment: @eddyrokr Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551033/difference-between-sh-and-bash-when-symlink-is-used

Comment: @eddyrokr BASH shell emulates the POSIX shell when called as `sh` vs. `bash`. The Posix shell has fewer features and the `[[..]]` is one of them. This was introduced with the Kornshell, and BASH took many of the Kornshell innovations.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $line | grep "$word"
```

would be the typical way to do this in a script, of course it does cost a new process

Comment: I get some messages:
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
I get this even after using the '-s' option while using grep.

Comment: Could be that `$word` starts with a hyphen, so it is safer to use `grep -- "$word"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the bash match operator `=~`:

```
 [[ "$line" =~ "$word" ]] && echo "$line"
```

Don't forget quotes, as stated in previous answers (especially the one of @Bill).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `if [ "$line"==*"$word"* ]` does not work as you expect is perhaps a bit obscure.  Assuming that no files exist that cause the glob to expand, then you are merely testing that the string `1234 abc xyz 5678==*1234*` is non empty.  Clearly, that is not an empty string, so the condition is always true.  You need to put whitespace around your `==` operator, but that will not work because you are now testing if the string `1234 abc xyz 5678` is the same as the string to which the glob `*1234*` expands, so it will be true only if a file named `1234 abc xyz 5678` exists in the current working directory of the process executing the shell script.  There are shell extensions that allow this sort of comparison, but `grep` works well, or you can use a case statement:

```
case "$line" in
*$word*) echo $line;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be using loop:

```
for w in $line
do
    if [ "$w" == "$word" ]; then
        echo $line
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code Snippet:**

```
$a='text'
$b='text'

if [ $a -eq $b ]
 then
   msg='equal'
fi
```